# error while compiling solr

Tags: solr, lucene

While compiling solr I got following error :

> /home/username/MP3/solr-4.1.0/build.xml:106: The following error
>   occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/username/MP3/solr-4.1.0/solr/common-build.xml:329: The following
>   error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/username/MP3/solr-4.1.0/solr/common-build.xml:349: The following
>   error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/username/MP3/solr-4.1.0/lucene/module-build.xml:229: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/username/MP3/solr-4.1.0/lucene/module-build.xml:141: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/username/MP3/solr-4.1.0/lucene/common-build.xml:464: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/username/MP3/solr-4.1.0/lucene/common-build.xml:592: Invalid
>   Manifest:
>   /home/username/MP3/solr-4.1.0/lucene/build/analysis/common/MANIFEST.MF

Comment: I don't know the answer for sure, but "invalid manifest" sounds like you have an incomplete set of source code.

Comment: okk will check it out. thanks.